# Why this system is unstable in the sense of Lyapunov?

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Given the following Lyapunov function
$$
V(x_1,x_2) = (x^2_1+x^2_2-1)^2
$$
Its time derivative is 
$$
\dot{V}(x_1,x_2) = -(x^2_1+x^2_2)
$$
Why the origin is unstable?

Comment: How can that be the time derivative?

Comment: To elaborate, $V(1,0) = 0$ but $\dot{V}(1,0) = -1$ which implies that $V$ becomes negative, an impossibility.